# What does the symbol $+: E\times E$ mean in $+: E\times E\to E$?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

What exactly does the symbol,  $ +: E\times E$ mean in the formula $+: E\times E\to E$? In other word why such a symbol/operation is used to represent addition in the vector space?

Comment: Is it $+ : E \times E \to E$?

Comment: Oh ,  Actually it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we write $f:A \rightarrow B$, we mean:

> $f$ is a function that takes an element from set $A$ and maps it to an element in set $B$.

In the case of $+: E \times E \rightarrow E$, the function is called $+$ (that is, addition), and it takes an element from set $E \times E$ (that is, an ordered pair of elements from $E$), and maps it to an element of $E$.

Simply put, it is a function that adds two elements from $E$ to get another element in $E$.

Since the function $+$ is so common, rather than writing $+(v,u)$ to denote addtion, we usually use *infix notation* and write $v+u$.

---

**EDIT**: To clarify ordered pairs...

You may have come across the idea of an ordered pair back in high school when talking about the $xy$-plane. You know that the ordered pair $(5,-3)$ means the point where $x=5$ and $y=-3$, not $x=-3$ and $y=5$. Because the pair is ordered, you know the first element is always the $x$ coordinate and the second element is always the $y$ coordinate.

If we have the sets $A = \{a,b,c\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3\}$, then the set $A \times B$ is the set of all ordered pairs where an element of $A$ comes first and an element of $B$ comes second. For example, $(a,1)$, $(c,2)$, and $(b,3)$ are all elements of $A \times B$. Because order matters, $(3,a)$ is not an element of the set $A \times B$. Rather, it is an element of the set $B \times A$. The $\times$ symbol here is called the *Cartesian product*.

In the case of the set $E \times E$, the order does not play as important of a role, but you can think of the first $E$ as giving us the element on the left of the $+$ sign and the second $E$ as giving us an element on the right of the $+$ sign. So when we put the element $(v,u)$ through the function $+$, we get $v+u$.

Comment: @eigenchiris: Thank you very much for your clear and simple explanation. Can you please elaborate more on when you say ordered pair of elements? what if it is not ordered?

Comment: @fery Hopefully my edited answer clears things up.

Comment: @eigenchiris: Thank you so much for your nice explanations.

Comment: @frey I'm glad they helped.

Comment: @eigenchiris: I checked you profile and found that you are also dealing with signal processing. I am electrical engineer as well and not so deep into math. I have one question that i think you can enlighten me up. The concept Hilbert space. I know the idea is related to Fourier series/transform in signal analysis (etc. The issue of convergence of both series/transform, energy, Parsaval). However with it comes to mathmatical context, we have Cauchy sequence, completeness,inner product space, etc.

Comment: @eigenchiris: I would like you to share your knowledge on Hilber space in the most comprehensive, intuitive and simple way. I am sorry if this has been asked here because i couldn't send private message.However, i can ask this as a separate question and share your answer. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @fery I think the best thing to do is search for questions similar to yours, and if you can't find an acceptable answer, ask the question yourself. I'll keep an eye out for your question and offer help if I can.

Comment: @eigenchiris: I already search for it, but couldn't find convincing answer. Anyway, i asked it as a separate question. plz follow it up.

Answer (score 1):

The *notation* "$+:E\times E\to E$" is exactly the same notation as $f:X\to Y$.

The function name is $+$, the domain is $E\times E$, and the codomain is $E$. Addition in a vector space $E$ is a special example of a function between these two sets.

Answer (score 0):

It is to symbolize that addition is an operator that takes two inputs from the vector space $E$ and then returns an element in $E$.

You may have seen the notation
$$f: A\to B $$
which means that $f$ is a function that maps an element from $A$ (the domain) into $B$ (the co-domain). This is basically the same. In this example the addition operator takes two inputs (i.e. from the domain $E\times E$) and returns and element in $E$ (the co-domain).

Answer (score 0):

It's like the definition of a function.. $$f: \mathbb R \times \mathbb C \mapsto \mathbb R$$

in this case they are telling you that the operator $+$ operates on two values taken from the same vector space $E$, that is $+: E \times E \mapsto \dots..$

And usually it maps into $E$ itself. There are other properties we usually attach to the operator $+$ when we talk about vector spaces, but that's not really relevant to your question